# How to correct this error for window.localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, local-storage

I want to save data using `window.localStorage.setItem` but I found this error:

> JavaScript ERROR: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'window.localStorage.setItem')

In my connexion.js

```
$("#btn-connexion").on('click', function() {    
    var username = $('#Identifiant').val();
    var password = $("#mdp").val();         

    console.log("********username*******password****");
    console.log(username);

    $.ajax({
        "url": serverPath + "/taxiws/clients/login/password/" + username + '/' + password,
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function(data) {
            console.log("****Resultat****");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));                   

            window.localStorage.setItem("login", username);
            window.localStorage.setItem('password', password);
            window.location.href = "reservationclient.html";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't sent the username and password as part of a plaintext URL. It's a ***massive*** security issue.

Comment: As @Rory McCrossan said - this is a security risk - NEVER store passwords oim localStorage - VERY UNSECURE

Comment: please help me to resolve my problem

Comment: It would be better if you take all your controls in a `form` and `submit` the form back to server to process it.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue on safari. My problem was that sometimes my site is loaded as an iframe. When the user was done with the iframe, I would close it with "window.close()". I forgot to remove this code if my site is not an iframe. On old versions of safari (cordova webview), this would leave the window open and remove localStorage.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if the browser supports `localStorage` by using the code below:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```